# Trilinos library: error adding symbols: file in wrong format

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, trilinos

I'm a newbie to C++ and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/). Recently I have been trying to set up NetBeans for my C++ project, which was developed by one of my colleagues 5 to 10 years ago, but I kept receiving compiler errors. We used [trilinos](https://trilinos.github.io/) for numerical simulation. There is no compiler error in my colleague's Linux desktop, but somehow I just couldn't set up NetBeans in my virtual Linux via [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/).

[image]

As shown above, I followed the NetBeans settings in his Linux desktop and added a library file `lib/trilinos/lib/libepetra.so.12` into the `Linker > Libraries`. Then I right clicked the project and selected `Build`, now here is the compiler error message.

```
cd '/root/Venus/Folders/MyProject'
/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile CONF=Serial
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Serial.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/root/Venus/Folders/MyProject'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Serial.mk dist/MyProject
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/root/Venus/Folders/MyProject'
mkdir -p dist
g++     -o dist/MyProject build/Serial/GNU-Linux/main.o -Llib/trilinos/lib -lboost_system lib/trilinos/lib/libepetra.so.12

/usr/bin/ld: lib/trilinos/lib/libepetra.so.12: error adding symbols: file in wrong format

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

gmake[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Serial.mk:65: dist/MyProject] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Venus/Folders/MyProject'
gmake[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Serial.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Venus/Folders/MyProject'
gmake: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 157ms)
```

**What I have checked**

1. **Path**: the path is correct. I also selected `Relative to Run Directory` for *Runtime Library Search Path*. If the path is incorrect, the compiler error message would be:

> gmake[2](https://trilinos.github.io/): *** No rule to make target 'lib/trilinos/liba/libepetra.so.12', needed by 'dist/MyProject'.  Stop.
>
> > (the folder ../liba/.. doesn't exist)

2. **g++ and C++ version**: G++ is 11.3.0 and C++ is C++11. However, the g++ on my colleague's desktop is 5.4.0.

> g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0 (g++ on my Linux)

3. **NetBeans version**: My NetBeans is version 14, while the one on my colleague's desktop is NetBeans 7 or 8. It's a very old version.

**What I am still trying to check:**

1. Trilinos version: I still don't know how to check it.

Could someone please help me? I have been struggling with it for several days. I would truly appreciate it! Thank you.

Comment: Does the `g++` command, executed in your command prompt, produce the same error?  This issue seems to have nothing to do with NetBeans and everything to do with how your specific version of g++ recognizes the file `libepetra.so.12`.

Comment: _"lib/trilinos/lib/libepetra.so.12: error adding symbols: file in wrong format"_ - looks  like a showstopper for using that particular release of the library. If it's 10 years old, look for a newer release and make sure it's for the correct target platform. Fwiw, "trilinos-release-14-2-0" seems to be the latest. Compile it yourself from source if you can't find binaries for your platform. It's on github

Comment: Thanks so much Drew Dormann and Ted Lyngmo for giving me these directions. I will start working on it and let you know once I have any results! Thank you again for narrowing down the issue for me!

Comment: By the way, the g++ version on my colleague's desktop is 5.4.0, but mine is 11.3.0. So yes, maybe it is due to the version mismatch between g++ and trilinos.

Comment: Looks like it's probably due to my arm64 architecture (Macbook Air M2 chip).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63832669/16926455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the root cause and just fixed it. It is because I used the libraries that are compiled on x86-64 (amd64) system, while my MacBook Air M2 is arm64 system. Their machine codes are different so my arm64 doesn't recognize the codes compiled by amd64 system.

```
> file libepetra.so.12
> libepetra.so.12: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=baf33e494c06b548b3c3fbfc159ead5d0424000c, not stripped
```

Compiling trilinos seems to be the only way to fix it, so I downloaded trilinos 13.0.0 and TriBITS to compile it. Below is my cmake command.

## Test system

- Macbook Air M2, 2022 (aarch64 architecture)
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (jammy) based on UTM Virtual Machine

## Instructions

1. Download [trilinos 13.0.0](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/releases/tag/trilinos-release-13-0-0) from GitHub. Unpack it.
2. Download [TriBITS](https://github.com/TriBITSPub/TriBITS) from GitHub. Unpack it.
3. Put TriBITS inside the trilinos folder.
4. Create a subfolder where you want to build trilinos. For example, `<path to trilinos unpacked folder>/build`
5. Go to the build folder and execute the command cmake listed below.

## non-MPI Trilinos

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gfortran \
-DTPL_ENABLE_MPI=OFF \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_AztecOO=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Epetra=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_EpetraExt=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Gtest=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Kokkos=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Teuchos=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Triutils=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_FLOAT=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Home/Venus/Folders/NetBeans_Project/MyProject/lib/trilinos \
-DTrilinos_TRIBITS_DIR:STRING=/Home/Venus/Folders/Trilinos-source-13.0.0/TriBITS/tribits \
-DTrilinos_TRIBITS_PACKAGE_USE_TRIBITS_DIR=TRUE \
/Home/Venus/Folders/Trilinos-source-13.0.0

make install
```

## MPI Trilinos

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mpicc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mpicxx \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mpif77 \
-DTPL_ENABLE_MPI=ON \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_AztecOO=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_Epetra=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_EpetraExt=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Gtest=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Kokkos=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Teuchos=ON \
-Dtrilinos_ENABLE_Triutils=ON \
-DTrilinos_ENABLE_FLOAT=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Home/Venus/Folders/NetBeans_Project/MyProject/lib/trilinos-mpi \
-DTrilinos_TRIBITS_DIR:STRING=/Home/Venus/Folders/Trilinos-source-13.0.0/TriBITS/tribits \
-DTrilinos_TRIBITS_PACKAGE_USE_TRIBITS_DIR=TRUE \
/Home/Venus/Folders/Trilinos-source-13.0.0

make install
```

Now use file command to check the *.so files. Problem solved!

```
> file libepetra.so.13.0
> libepetra.so.13.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=6593cc6bd0543c5823989303085c9472200fe144, not stripped
```